# Shaka/shawaka: An introduction

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, polyomino

This is a shaka/shawaka puzzle. Place black triangles in some white cells in the grid – formed by dividing a cell diagonally and painting one side black – so that each remaining white area forms the shape of a tetromino. The white area can be any size as long as its  proportions exactly match some tetromino. For example, 2x8 is a valid I piece but 2x7 is not, and 1x1 is a valid O piece but 1x2 is not. In addition, numbers in black cells indicate how many triangles in total are in the cells orthogonally adjacent to that number cell.

TL;DR [Shakashaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakashaka) but the aim is forming tetrominoes instead of rectangles.

[image: Empty shaka/shawaka grid]

[Penpa link](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/#m=solve&p=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)

Comment: Penpa link was missing a number originally (fixed now). Sorry about that!

Comment: The puzzle is still uniquely solvable without the top 2 and bottom 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had never played this game before, so thanks for the interesting puzzle. I will note down here how I tackled this problem, briefly.

For convenience, I will lable the grid as below.

[image: Notation]

### Procedure

The first obvious thing is that,

> if a cell lies next to the margin of the grid, it should be filled with a triangle such that one edge is lying on the margin, or it should be left empty.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: wrong] | [image: correct] |
| $$\color{red}{\unicode{x2718}}$$ | $$\color{green}{\unicode{x2714}}$$ |

---

Now, there are several places to start. (I'll explain them separately, while presenting them in one image.)

1. Consider the cells containing number 3.

> With aforementioned property, we can fill the two adjacent cells of each which lie on the margin. Now to create a tetromino, the two cells along the dotted line should contain ⬕s. And this will create our first square-tetromino in A10.

2. Now move to region H5-J9.

> The cells in the range J6-J8 and I7 cannot be filled with triangles, so they must be left empty to create an L-tetromino. Therefore, the marked edges (green) should contain the edge of the triangles outside.

3. Consider 0.

> J1, I2 and J3 cannot contain triangles, obviously.

> [image: image1]

---

Continuing from 0,

4. > we see that I1 too cannot be filled with any type of triangle. So it should be left empty. Then if we leave I3 empty, we will get a pentomino. Thus I3 should be filled with a triangle, and the only possiblity is ⬔.
5. > To extend J1-I1-I2 to a tetromino, there are two possibilities; T or skew-tetromino. To create a skew-tetromino, H1 should be filled with ◪, but that contradicts the earlier mentioned margin law. Therefore placing a ⬔ will give a T-tetromino as the only way.
6. > And immediately, we can place a ⬔ in G1.

> [image: image2]

---

7. Consider the four cells at bottom right corner.

> Since J10 has to be a ◪, those four cells should present a square-tetromino.

8. Then go to H8.

> We can form an L-tetromino containing it, but we will get in trouble with G9. Similarly we cannot attach it to a skew-tetromino because of H10. Hence, we have to leave it isolated as a square-tetromino, and fill G9-H10 as same as I9-J10.

9. Back to J3 again.

> Currently, it cannot be a part of an L or a skew-tetromino. Therefore leave it as it is and after we can fill J4 with a ⬔.

> [image: image3]

---

10. > Fill F10 with a ◪ and use the cells above E10 and F10 to complete square-tetromino.
11. > Similarly, we can fill F1 with a ◩.

> [image: image4]

---

12. Obviously, D9 should be a

> ◪. This will pave the way for a large square-teromino.

13. In the same manner, we see I5 must be filled with a

> ⬕, predicting a large 1×4 tetromino.

> [image: image5]

---

14. Now consider the three free sqaures in E7-F9.

> Since G7 can be guaranteed to be filled with a ⬕, these three must along with F6 make an L-tetromino.

15. And we can complete H6 and G6,

> to create a square-tetromino.

> [image: image6]

---

16. Due to marginal conditions of E6,

> it must be a ◪.

17. B6 can only be a

> ◪ which says that A5 should be a ◩.

18. Then,

> We can't create a valid tetromino in the region marked in dotted lines below, therefore the two cells just filled should participate in a square-tetromino.

> [image: Image7]

---

19. Considering the currently empty cells in G4-H5,

> we see that F5 should be a ⬕, and those cells should make an O-tetromino with it as the only possible way.

> [image: image8]

---

20. We cannot do anything with D7,

> as it cannot be a part of any other tetromino other than an O. Therefore it will be empty.

21. Therefore D6 and E5,

> must be ⬕ and ⬔ respectively.

> [image: image9]

---

22. In the region, A2-E6,

> a large straight-tetromino can be formed with several other square-tetrominoes.

23. Now consider the last hint; the cell with number 2.

> The adjacent unfilled cells in the range E2-F4 must create a T-tetromino.

> [image: image10]

---

24. As the last step,

> You know what to do : )

> [image: image11]

---

Here is our finalized grid!

> [image: answer]

<sup>Also thanks to OP for providing the Penpa link.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

1. orange, then pink is easy
2. expand with red and brown
3. realize the light green is needed, enlarging those areas causes problems; and then also dark green
4. the blues finish the puzzle

The picture

> [image]